# ggplot using facet_wrap of multiple data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I am trying to `ggplot` `D2` on the same figure as of `D1`. I, however, do not have data for the Variable `X` in `D2` `data.frame`. How i can plot `D2` on its respective `facets` of `D1 plot`? these plots represent data for `2011` and `2014` so i would like to have `legends` for the `line` to differentiate which `line` represent which `year` data.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1500)

D1 <- data.frame(Day = 1:8, A = runif(8, 2,16), S = runif(8, 3,14), X = runif(8, 5,10), Z = runif(8, 1,12), Year = rep("2011",8))
D2 <- data.frame(Day = 1:8, A = runif(8, 2,14), S = runif(8, 1,13),  Z = runif(8, 3,14), Year = rep("2014",8))

# plotting D1
 D1 %>% gather(-c(Day, Year), key = "Variable", value = "Value") %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x = Day, y = Value))+
  geom_line()+facet_wrap(~Variable,  scales = "free_y", nrow=2)

# Plotting D2 on top ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about convert two DFs to long format then merge them together before plotting?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1500)

D1 <- data.frame(Day = 1:8, A = runif(8, 2,16), S = runif(8, 3,14), 
                 X = runif(8, 5,10), Z = runif(8, 1,12), Year = rep("2011",8))
D1_long <- D1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Day, Year),
               names_to = 'Variable',
               values_to = 'Value')

D2 <- data.frame(Day = 1:8, A = runif(8, 2,14), S = runif(8, 1,13),  
                 Z = runif(8, 3,14), Year = rep("2014",8))
D2_long <- D2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Day, Year),
               names_to = 'Variable',
               values_to = 'Value')

### merge two data frames
DF <- bind_rows(D1_long, D2_long)

my_linetype <- setNames(c("dashed", "solid"), unique(DF$Year))

# plot DF
DF %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = Value, 
             color = Year,
             linetype = Year))+
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ Variable,  scales = "free_y", nrow = 2) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Dark2') +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = my_linetype) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2.5, 'lines'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Tung, is there any way to make the 2011 `line` as `dashed` line?

Comment: You just need to add `linetype = Year` inside `aes()`. Plz see my update